# Difference between a nested task and a separate task

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to understand the concept of nested tasks in TPL. In what condition it is better to create the nested task instead of creating two separate tasks because in case of nested task, it is completely independent of the parent.

Is there any performance gain by using the local queue of the parent task?

Comment: Could you describe what exactly do you mean by “nested task”?

Comment: Hi SVICK, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx . A nested task is just a System.Threading.Tasks.Task instance that is created in the user delegate of another task. A child task is a nested task that is created with the AttachedToParent option.I want to understand the purpose of Nested tasks and how it can be useful or when should i use it....

Answer (score 0):

Here's the msdn [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx) on this.

First of all, a "nested task" just means you start a new task within another task, like the following:

```
var outerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
{
    var nestedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Inside nestedTask");
    });
});
```

What you probably meant was what is the difference between a "Nested Task" and "Child Task"

A "child task" looks like this:

```
var parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
{
    var childTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Inside childTask");
    },               TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent );
});
```

Child tasks will enforce certain synchronizations with the Parent task.

Since, child tasks will always have higher synchronization overhead than independent nested tasks, it makes you wonder why you might want to use them at all.

Sometimes you want to ensure synchronization of these tasks. You want the childTask to calculate something before the parent task completes. Other times, it might just make debugging easier, since you will have to deal with a little less non-determinism.

Less non-determinism, may help you write and test your code faster.

It is possible, though I'm not certain it is implemented this way, for child tasks to be injected on the same thread/core as the parent, especially when the parent is simply waiting for the child task. In this case you might be able to get added benefits of caching from the parent task in the child task.

(It seems like a nice idea, but I don't think it's implemented that way yet, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Sorry, u got me completely wrong..i want to know the need to create the nested task and what is the advantage we can get out of it instead of creating the new task...

Comment: @RaoBHavik the second half of my answer describes that you use it for synchronizations, and to reason about the program easier, but with an associated slow down due to synchronization. There's not any other difference that I know of.